# cancel dhclient eth0 command on linux

Tags: dhcp, dhclient

I accidently run on my computer :

`dhclient eth0`

and now i cant ssh to my computer by it's ip.
restart the computer didn't help.
How can i cancel this command or fix it?

thank you for helping!

Comment: Right after posting my answer i noticed that you mention that a reboot doesn't work. This sound strange, in most cases this would mean it never worked at all. Did you really run `dhclient` manually or did you put in some startup script (or changed your netwerkconfiguration in some file)

Answer (score 1):

- Kill the dhcp-client: `killall dhclient`
- Bring your card down: `ifconfig eth0 down`
- Manually provide a ip and netmask to your networkcard and bring it back up: `ifconfig eth0 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
- Configure routing: `route add default gw 1.2.3.1`
- Configure DNS: `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf`

(This assumes your ip is `1.2.3.4`, your netmask is `255.255.255.0` (which is `/24`, your gateway is `1.2.3.1` and you want to use a dns-server of google (`8.8.8.8`))

**Edit:** I added some tests. Also noteworthy is that I skipped IPv6 in my answer.

And if it still fails test where it fails, try the following things in this order:

- `ping 127.0.0.1` -> When this fails all forms of networking are broken or you messed up your firewall configuration.
- `ping 1.2.3.4` -> When this fails your card is still down or you failed to provide it with the correct ip
- `ping 1.2.3.1` -> When this fails your netmask is incorrect or there are other problems between you and the first router.
- `ping -4 google.com` -> When this fails DNS is configured incorrectly.